# Use AsyncFileUpload in a grid view in update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, asyncfileupload

I want to use a AsyncFileUpload in a grid view and each record must have a AsyncFileUpload individually. In addition user must be able to upload his/her file for each record. 
Now how can i access AsyncFileUpload in the grid view and check it if it has a file or not?
For common file upload i have used the below cod:

```
((FileUpload)GridView1.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload).HasFile
```

However, it is not acceptable in this situation. 
Is there any way to access this Ajax controller in a grid view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your asyncfileupload bind OnUploadedComplete event to the method

```
OnUploadedComplete = "FileUploded"
```

code:

```
protected Sub FileUploded(object sender, EventArgs e)

    Dim fu AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload

    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(fu.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim idx = row.RowIndex

    fu = ctype(sender,AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload)
    If fu.HasFile then
    --do something--
    End If 
End Sub
```

c#:

```
protected void FileUploded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AsyncFileUpload fu = (AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload)sender;

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)fu.NamingContainer;
    string idx = row.RowIndex.toString();       
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But i need  the following code there too:
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Upload", "~/InputReviewer/" + MainFileName)
For that i need idx which i should extract it from command button. 
I need to extract idx from table and save the upload file within a it's ID in the database. Is there any way?

Comment: I updated the code with how to get row index. You can extract any value in any column this way.

Comment: Thank you. Just two problems:
1- ctype is not recognizable! Dose it need any namespace?
2- How should i write this code in C# language:
  Dim fu AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload

Comment: Only one more thing please, as i mentioned ctype and AsyncFileUpload  is not recognizable in behind cod! Do they need a name space?

Comment: CType is vb.net so if you are with c#, forget it. and include this in your xaml: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
 use ajax as prifix in xaml

Comment: Thank you so much, dose CType has any alternative in C#?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49380/discussion-between-voddy-and-saeed-talaee)

Comment: Is there any way that all these happen when i click on a button in grid view?

Comment: As i used it in command button, it gave me the following error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload'.

Comment: I have just posted it.